# Find domain of $g(0.5, -g(2, f(x)) - 1)$ where $f(x) = 1 + \frac{1}{x^{1/4}}$ and $g(x, y) = \log_x{y}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, solution-verification

> Let $$f(x) = 1 + \frac{1}{x^{\frac{1}{4}}}$$ and $$g(x, y) = \log_x{y}$$ Find the largest possible domain of $$g\bigg(\frac{1}{2}, -g(2, f(x)) - 1\bigg)$$

Hello, my answer to this question is that the domain is the empty set.

My Solution:

$$-g(2, f(x)) - 1 > 0$$
$$g(2, f(x)) < -1$$
$$\log_2(f(x)) < -1$$
$$f(x) < \frac{1}{2}$$
$$1 + \frac{1}{x^{\frac{1}{4}}} < \frac{1}{2}$$
which is never true.

Is my work correct?

Thanks

Comment: It is unclear to me if $g$ is a single variable or two-variable function here? When you write $g(x)=\dots$ that usually means it is one-variable function. But then what is $g(1/2, -g(2, f(x)) - 1)$ ?

Comment: @sadman-ncc really sorry for the typo. It is $$g(x, y) = \log_x{y}$$

Comment: @sadman-ncc the inequality should be reversed.

Comment: @MangoPizza reverse the inequality

Comment: @LOL Where is the inequality reversed?